# Why additional code and complexity when data model and interaction are simple is considered a disadvantage in MVC model

Tags: mvc

According to the slides given by my lecturer, one of the disadvantages of [MVC model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is

> additional code and complexity when data model and interaction are simple

Why is this so, I would assume it would make no difference since data model and interaction are on two different components of the MVC model?

Comment: That statement is not claiming that simple interactions in MVC add additional complexity over complex interactions; it is claiming that simple interactions in MVC require more code than the same interactions without MVC. i.e. I can show a list of users with a bit of SQL and `print` but with MVC I would have to do a lot more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the whole point.  When it is simple, you don't need two different components, and all that structure becomes overhead.  It's like turning on an industrial bakery to make one doughnut.  A certain amount of inherent complexity is required to make the overhead of the framework worth it.

Comment: But that's one _industrial-strength_ donut.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, model and interactions are different components of MVC but, they are related through the relationship of MVC.

If you have a very simple project with a few data and a little interaction, the MVC frameworks would generate a lot of code for something that no need this kind of complexity. But if your project starts to grow up you will have to change to MVC if you didn't before in order to maintain your code.

So yes there is an additional complexity when the data model and the interaction are simple, but if your project starts to grow this complexity would help you to maintain your code easily